# VBA spitting out error at seemingly arbitrary time?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array of formulas that I am filling across all relevant columns on Row 2. After that, I have code that fills the range with dynamic references. This particular data set has 74 rows of data, but for some reason the receive the

> 438 Error: 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

at row 65 every time.

```
     'Find last row/col variables
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim lastCol As Long
        'Array variable
        Dim TestFormulas() As Variant
       'WS variable
         Dim WS as Worksheet

    lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

lastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

'Create Array [this is cut down significantly. There are roughly 50 formulas here. Code runs quickly, if it matters.]
TestFormulas() = Array( _
                  "=Sheet1!H2", "=Sheet1!B2", "=IF(Sheet1!P2=""Resiliency""") 

'Fill Row 2 with formulas
 With WS
    For i = LBound(TestFormulas()) To UBound(TestFormulas())
      .Cells(2, 1 + i).Formula = TestFormulas(i)
    Next i
 End With

'Copy formulas and fill down the entire range 
 Range("A2:" & lastCol & ":" & "2").Formula = TestFormulas
 Range("A2:" & WS(1).lastCol & ":" & WS(1).lastRow).FillDown
```

I am expecting the range to fill with the dynamic formula. It fills, dynmically at that, though only up to and including row 65.

> 438 Error: 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: `Range("A2:" & lastCol & ":" & "2")` lastcol is a number so it would concat to `A2:52:2`  which is not a valid range address.  You need to use `Cells()` which accepts a numeric column, inside the Range Object.

Comment: Also are you sure you can do `...Formula = [array of formulas]`? You may need to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lastRow As Long

'Array variable
Dim TestFormulas() As Variant
'WS variable
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet4") ' change to your sheet name

With WS
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells) > 0 Then
        lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row


        'Create Array [this is cut down significantly. There are roughly 50 formulas here. Code runs quickly, if it matters.]
        TestFormulas() = Array( _
        "=Sheet1!H2", "=Sheet1!B2", "=IF(Sheet1!P2=""Resiliency"",TRUE,FALSE)")

        'Fill Row 2 with formulas

        For i = LBound(TestFormulas()) To UBound(TestFormulas())
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1 + i), .Cells(lastRow, 1 + i)).Formula = TestFormulas(i)
        Next i
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Hey again, Scott! I can only get it to populate across the entirety of row #1 with this code. If it makes any difference, I already have it set to create and activate a new sheet, so I did not use the Set WS = Worksheets ("Sheet4") line.

Comment: So you are looking for the last row in a different sheet?  See edit.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I see my error. It was only accounting for that 1 row of data and then filling based on that, rather than accounting for the data on the previous sheet. Thank you sir!